# Matlab `bar`: Control spacing between bar groups

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

The following creates pairs of bars:

```
x = rand(10,2);
hBar = bar(x)
```

There is a lot of space between each pair.  How can I decrease the spacing between the pairs (not between the bars within each pair)?

`get(h(1))` does not reveal any likely properties to alter.  Property `BarWidth` only controls the spacing between bars within each pair.

The Properties editor also does not reveal likely candidates.

I am using Matlab 2015b.

**Afternote:** Specifying a wide `width` argument to `bar` widens each bar without changing their positions relative to each other, so that will certainly shrink the gap between groups of bars.  However, it also causes the bars within each group to overlap.

Comment: Per [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html): `bar(x,y)` draws the bars at the locations specified by `x`, rather than at their integer index in `y`.

Comment: I tried `hBar = bar(0.5*(1:10),x)`, and yes, the scaling of the x-axis changes, but the relative width of the bars compared to the space between groups doesn't seem to change.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB R2017a, `bar(...,'hist')` uses an older style bar graph, not using the `Bar` graphics objects, but using the more low-level `Patch` graphics objects. (I'm specifying the version number, because this is not something mentioned in the documentation, so it's possible that a newer release does this differently.)

I was able to modify the vertex locations for these `Patch` objects to shift the bars, increasing the space within the groups and decreasing the space between groups. By default, the bars within groups were touching using the `'hist'` option.

```
x = rand(10,2);
hBar = bar(x,'hist');

v = hBar(1).Vertices;
v(:,1) = v(:,1) - 0.1; % shift x locations left
hBar(1).Vertices = v;

v = hBar(2).Vertices;
v(:,1) = v(:,1) + 0.1; % shift x locations right
hBar(2).Vertices = v;
```

It should be relatively easy to modify the code above for more fine-tuned bar placement. Note that each bar uses 5 vertices. In the case of 2 bars, the left one has round values on the right and the right one has round values on the left. You can identify these values through `mod(v(:,1),1)==1`. But for more bars this will not hold. Maybe separately adjusting values `v(ii:5:end,1)`, for ii from 1 to 5, would be the simplest approach.

Comment: Thanks, Cris.  I think that'll do in a pinch, for the 2-series example.  One would need to also adjust the x-coordinates of the patches to widen them so that they abut.  It's the abutment that makes the membership in each group obvious, thus making it possible to lessen the spacing between groups.

Comment: I noticed that the `Width` argument is normalized to some value that is determined within the `bar` function For more than 2 bars per group, the generalization of adjusting vertices and widths would take some recoding. It might be easier to code up one's own patch-based `bar` function. I think that for the generalized case, that general approach would be the practical answer.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure how to handle an answer that addresses the example, but perhaps might be overly onerous for the general case. Would it be in the spirit of Stack Exchange to mark it as the answer?  If you can add the comment about the approach for the general case, I'd like to mark yours as the answer (unless you see a guileful way to avoid the need to write a custom patch-based `bar` from scratch).

Comment: @user36800: I guess you accept the answer if it solved your problem, and upvote it if it was helpful. It’s up to you to interpret what that means for you. — I don’t know if creating your own patches is any more or less work than modifying the existing ones. You can also try the `rectangle` function, which might be simpler.

Comment: I'll upvote it.  It's quite insightful.  To me, however, a complete answer would include mention of the considerations behind possibly coding a plotting function from scratch, with mention of your `rectangle` function.  I thought it would be relatively simple to mention, but then again, they are my opinons.

Comment: @user36800: I don’t think plotting your own bars using patches or `rectangle` is any easier than modifying the patches created by `bar`. If you do go that route, you should post your code as answer. :)

Comment: At present, I don't consider recoding in any significant capacity to be worthwhile.  I'm just living with the lack of control.  That could change in the future, but that's my situation for now.